# validar grupo de checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, html

estoy tratando un grupo de checkbox

```html
<div id="a">
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="A1" class="licencia" id="a1"/>A1-Motocicletas hasta 125 c.c de cilindrada</label> <input type="date" id="fechaA1"  disabled=true/><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="A2" class="licencia" id="a2"/>A2-Motocicletas, motociclos y motiriclicos de más de 125 c.c de cilindrada</label><br>
     </div>
     <div id="b">
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="B1" class="licencia" id="b1"/>B1-Automoviles, camperos, camionetas y microbuses de servicio particular</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="B2" class="licencia" id="b2"/>B2-Camiones, rígidos,buesetas y buses para servicio particular</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="B3" class="licencia" id="b3"/>B3-Vehículos articulados de servicio particular</label><br>
     </div>
     <div id="c">
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="C1" class="licencia" id="c1"/>C1-Automoviles, camperos, camionetas y microbuses de servicio publico</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="C2" class="licencia" id="c2"/>C2-Camiones, rígidos,buesetas y buses para servicio publico</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="C3" class="licencia" id="c3"/>C3-Vehículos articulados de servicio publico</label><br>
     </div>
```

de todos esos solo debe escoger maximo 3 y minimo 1 y cuando seleccione alguno se deberia aparecer un textbox donde se ponga la fecha de vencimiento de la categoria, he buscado por todo lado y no he encontrado como.

agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

Comment: es decir en cada checkbox aparecera un texto con fecha de vencimiento..si selecciono 3 checkbox apareceran 3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te he hecho el codigo en JS puro, esta todo comentado para que lo entiendas. Aqui tienes el código

```js
//variable para controlar cuantos checks hay marcados
var marcats = 0;
var checks = document.getElementsByClassName("licencia");
for (let check of checks) {
    //añadimos un evento a cada check
    check.addEventListener("click", function () {
        //si se ha marcado
        if (this.checked) {
            //si se ha pasado el numero maximo de checks
            if (marcats == 3) {
                alert("No puedes marcar más");
                //descmarcamos el check que marcó usuario
                this.checked = false;
            //si no se ha pasado el numero maximo de checks
            } else {
                //creamos el input y lo añadimos
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.id = "fecha" + this.id;
                input.disabled = "true";
                input.type = "date";
                this.parentNode.appendChild(input);
                marcats++;
            }
        //si se ha desmarcado
        } else {
            //si no queda solo uno marcado
            if (marcats != 1) {
                marcats--;
                //eliminamos el input
                document.getElementById("fecha" + this.id).remove();
            } else {
                //si solo queda uno marcado
                alert("Como minimo uno marcado");
                //marcamos el que quería desmarcar
                this.checked = true;
            }
        }
    })
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="A1" class="licencia" id="a1"/>A1-Motocicletas hasta 125 c.c de cilindrada</label> <input type="date" id="fechaA1"  disabled=true/><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="A2" class="licencia" id="a2"/>A2-Motocicletas, motociclos y motiriclicos de más de 125 c.c de cilindrada</label><br>
     </div>
     <div id="b">
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="B1" class="licencia" id="b1"/>B1-Automoviles, camperos, camionetas y microbuses de servicio particular</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="B2" class="licencia" id="b2"/>B2-Camiones, rígidos,buesetas y buses para servicio particular</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="B3" class="licencia" id="b3"/>B3-Vehículos articulados de servicio particular</label><br>
     </div>
     <div id="c">
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="C1" class="licencia" id="c1"/>C1-Automoviles, camperos, camionetas y microbuses de servicio publico</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="C2" class="licencia" id="c2"/>C2-Camiones, rígidos,buesetas y buses para servicio publico</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="C3" class="licencia" id="c3"/>C3-Vehículos articulados de servicio publico</label><br>
     </div>
```

Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto era lo que estaba buscando!!!

Comment: pero en que parte cargo el script??? en el onload?

Comment: Si, claro, o en lo mas bajo del documento html dentro de la etiqueta script para que sea lo utlimo que se lea

Comment: Lo pongo al final y no funciona

Comment: Hola @Ivan Isayenko, ya pe corrio el codigo, gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Perfecto! Me alegro de que te sirviera.

Answer (score 1):

Saludos podrias hacer algo como esto:

```
<div id="a">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" value="A1" class="licencia" id="a1" />A1-Motocicletas hasta 125 c.c de cilindrada</label> <input type="date" id="fechaA1"  disabled=true/><br>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" value="A2" class="licencia" id="a2"/>A2-Motocicletas, motociclos y motiriclicos de más de 125 c.c de cilindrada</label><br>
                    </div>
                    <div id="b">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" value="B1" class="licencia" id="b1"/>B1-Automoviles, camperos, camionetas y microbuses de servicio particular</label><br>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" value="B2" class="licencia" id="b2"/>B2-Camiones, rígidos,buesetas y buses para servicio particular</label><br>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" value="B3" class="licencia" id="b3"/>B3-Vehículos articulados de servicio particular</label><br>
                    </div>
                    <div id="c">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" value="C1" class="licencia" id="c1"/>C1-Automoviles, camperos, camionetas y microbuses de servicio publico</label><br>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" value="C2" class="licencia" id="c2"/>C2-Camiones, rígidos,buesetas y buses para servicio publico</label><br>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" value="C3" class="licencia" id="c3"/>C3-Vehículos articulados de servicio publico</label><br>
                    </div>
<input type="button" value="Validar" onclick="validar();">
<script>
function validar(){
  total_seleccionados = 0
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
     total_seleccionados+=1;
    }
  });
  if(total_seleccionados >3){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
   alert('Seleccione un maximo de 3');
  }else if(total_seleccionados == 1 || total_seleccionados == 3 ){
    alert('Bien selecciono :'+total_seleccionados+' opción');
  }else{
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
    alert('error- Debe seleccionar maximo 3 minimo 1 opcion');
  }
}
</script>
```

Si te fijas mediante la función each recorro uno a uno los checkbox para verificar si estan seleccionados, en caso de que esten seleccionados sumo el total de seleccionados y con un if valido que sea minimo 1 y maximo 3 caso contrario los deselecciono y muestro un mensaje.

espero te sirva y te guie.!!

Comment: Me podria servir, pero lo que me gustaria es que de cada div solo me dejara escoger uno, como puedes ver son 3 grupos, lo que me gustaria es que se comportara como los radio buttons que solo puedes escoger uno, pero en este caso se podrian escoger 1 de cada gruo, estuve buscando en internet y con jquery se puede con la funcion live, pero cuando la corro, me sale un error en esa linea, no se que mas hacer

Comment: en efecto con jquery puedes hacerlo, en esta respuesta es con jquery